# Different styles depending if the number of checked boxes is odd or even

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm running tests with CSS and SASS and have a series of selectors that are the same one repeated and nested several times, I want to simplify my code but don't know how to do it (it should be possible, but I can't figure it out).

The main idea is that I have a good number of radio buttons (84, in 42 sets of 2 with the same name) and want to add styles to an element depending if the number of radio buttons checked is odd or even.

To do that, right now I'm using `&` in SASS to generate the current selector, and nest it with the sibling selector `~` (order is not important, just the number of checked radios). This is a reduced version of the SASS code (with only 10 groups):

```css
.rd:checked {
  & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & {
    ~ #oddeven {
      background: red; // red if even
    }
  }
  &,
  & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &,
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & {
    ~ #oddeven {
      background: green; // green if odd 
    }
  }
}
```

That generates the following CSS code (I add the HTML so the effect I want is visible):

```css
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

.rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven,
.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

#oddeven {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />

<div id="oddeven">
  RED background if even number of checked radios (or nothing).<br/>
  GREEN background if odd number of checked radios.
</div>
```

---

Is there a way to reduce/simplify the SASS code so it is cleaner? The way it is right now, it's easy to make a mistake and it is complicated to add new rules (for new sets of radio buttons).

And alternatively, is it possible to do it in a better way? (maybe using a mixin or actually nesting in some way). Instead of using `&` and `~`, I tried using CSS counters, but I didn't find a way to add styles depending on the value of the counter.

NOTE: **I don't want to use JavaScript**, just HTML and CSS/SASS to generate the rules.

Comment: What you have here is *logic*, which is best handled in JavaScript. If you insist on doing it with CSS, you're going to have messy results like this.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I understand that. I don't mind if the generated code is messy. what I am more concerned about is having a cleaner/easier to maintain SASS code. It's a really repetitive structure, so probably there's an simpler way of doing it than how I'm doing it.

Comment: And at that point, I understand that maybe this question could be suitable for Code Review...

Comment: haha :p another one ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes. For a simpler game, I found counting the number of checked radio buttons was an alternative way of automatically changing from one player to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate those `& ~ & ...` selectors using [`for` loop](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while), [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) and concatenation:

```
// function to repeat string:
@function r($string, $times) { 
  $result: "";
  @if $times >= 1 {
    @for $i from 1 through $times {
      $result: $result + $string;
    }
  }
  @return $result;
}

// generate rules:
@for $n from 1 through 10 {
  .rd:checked {
    $s: r(' ~ &', $n - 1);
    $s: '&' + $s;
    @if ($n % 2 == 0) {
      #{$s} ~ #oddeven {
        background: red;
      }
    } @elseif ($n % 2 == 1) {
      #{$s} ~ #oddeven {
        background: green;
      }
    }
  }
}

#oddeven {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

I know it doesn't produce the exact same CSS as yours, but with some more playing that can be achieved too.

Working demo:

```css
.rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

.rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ .rd:checked ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}

#oddeven {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />

<div id="oddeven">
  RED background if even number of checked radios (or nothing).<br/>
  GREEN background if odd number of checked radios.
</div>
```

Comment: I tried and it works fine. It may be a bit _obscure_, but it simplifies the whole thing and it makes it easier to add new sets of radio buttons. Thanks!

Comment: There is a [cross post in Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/188201/250). If you want to reply there (it will have to be in Spanish), or I can translate your answer and share it as a wiki answer referencing this post.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Unfortunately I don't speak Spanish, please translate and share my answer there. :)

Comment: I created the [answer on Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189396/250) crediting your post. I also credited this answer on the [small project I developed with it](https://codepen.io/alvaromontoro/pen/rrPZwX). Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Thanks for the translation and the credit! And that project looks great :)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in CSS without manually doing it as you have done here.

However, when CSS4 selectors become available, you could use `:nth-child()` and `:last-child` together.

```css
.rd:last-of-type:nth-child(even of :checked) ~ #oddeven {
  background: red;
}
.rd:last-of-type:nth-child(odd of :checked) ~ #oddeven {
  background: green;
}

#oddeven {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd0" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd1" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd2" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd3" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd4" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd5" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd6" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd7" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd8" /><br/>
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />
<input type="radio" class="rd" name="rd9" />

<div id="oddeven">
  RED background if even number of checked radios (or nothing).<br/>
  GREEN background if odd number of checked radios.
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure it will work? last-of-type consider a type and not a class I guess .. I also don't get the nth-child logic here

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sharing this approach, it's really interesting. I was reviewing the definition for this and, disregarding the lack of browser support, it seems that for it to work I would need to add a new checked radio button at the end, no? As it could happen that the last of the type is not checked, then the second pseudo-class would not be fulfilled.